# Huge space between vaadin panels

Tags: java, vaadin

This piece of code that I wrote creates 2 panels. The aim is to have one of them directly on top of the other with no space in between, but the problem is that there is a huge gap between them.

Cann anyone help me out with this?

Code:

```
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        Panel Logo = new Panel();

        VerticalLayout layout1 = new VerticalLayout();
        VerticalLayout layout2 = new VerticalLayout();
        panel.setWidth("500px");
        panel.setHeight("300px");
        Logo.setWidth("500px");
        Logo.setHeight("100px");
        Logo.addStyleName(Runo.PANEL_LIGHT);
        Label label = new Label("test");
        label.setWidth(null);
        Button test = new Button("test");
        first.setStyleName("test");;
        first.setClickShortcut(KeyCode.ENTER, null);

        layout1.addComponent(test);
        layout2.addComponent(label);
        layout.addComponent(Logo);
        layout.addComponent(panel);
        layout.setComponentAlignment(panel, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
        layout1.setComponentAlignment(test, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
        layout2.setComponentAlignment(label, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
        layout.setSizeFull();
        layout1.setSizeFull();
        layout2.setSizeFull();
        setContent(layout);
        panel.setContent(layout1);
        Logo.setContent(layout2);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on the type of `layout`, which you have set to full size. Your `layout` will expand as much as the browser itself. What happens is that if your `layout` is a `VerticalLayout`, its height is 100% but it only has two panels with heights of 300 and 100, respectively. Since you did not specify any [expand ratio](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/layout.orderedlayout.html), Vaadin assigns 50% of the screen to the `panel` and the other 50% to the `Logo`, hence you get a big gap in between.

To fix it, you can do two things:

1. Don't use `layout.setSizeFull();` Instead, use `layout.setSizeUndefined();`
2. Play with expand ratio, so that the top `panel` gets less space and `Logo` gets more space: `layout.setExpandRatio(panel, 0.2f);` and `layout.setExpandRatio(Logo, 0.8f);`. The problem with this approach is that in case your browser height is less than 400 pixels, your layout will be cut off.

It took me a while and many trial/errors to learn this concept. Make sure you carefully read [this](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/layout.orderedlayout.html) page before going forward.

Comment: You typoed the name of the expand ratio method. It's "Ratio" not "Ration".

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! layout.setSizeUndefined(); did the trick, but the components are all stuck to the left now and alignment does not work. Do you know why?

Comment: That's because their enclosing parents (`layout1` and `layout2`) are full size, i.e. their width and height are 100%. To fix that, just set the size of `layout1` and `layout2` undefined as well (`layout1.setSizeUndefined();`). In addition, I believe you don't really need `layout1` and `layout2` anyways. Just add `panel` and `Logo` directly under `layout`.

Comment: A good way to see what you can do to make your layouts look exactly the way you want is to inspect the HTML code of the resulting page in Chrome or Safari and play with height and width to get the right layout.

Comment: "Make sure you carefully read this page before going forward." - really worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this :

- as @Abbas said use

  `layout.setExpandRatio(panel, float);`
- or you can add a property in the css file:

  `layout.setStyleName("my-layout");`

in css you add :

```
.v-verticallayout-my-layout .v-slot{
  height: auto !important;
}
```

This will do the job. I've tried both methods and they worked.